# how to send auto notification sms to a mobile number in Android?

Tags: android, sms

I am developing an application in android which can book the flights for the users. I want to send an automatic sms to the user's phone number that "Your Flight Has Been Booked".
Simple SMS applications send sms from my number to some other, but i want to send an sms by internet.
Kindly help.

Comment: You need to use an online SMS provider. Check on Clickatell, Tropo and Twilio

Comment: You mean to tell us, that each and every user will receive an SMS from your phone, when the "Flight has been booked"? If you even have 50 users this has to be automated, for example a flag, which to indicate to the application (via a pop-up Dialog) that the "Flight is booked". You can't do this action manually, if that's the final requirement for your application.

Comment: No I clearly mentioned that i don't want to use my number to send notification messages, rather internet.